# I'm deallocating objects created but I'm unsure whether my code is leaking memory or not

Tags: c++, object-oriented, memory-management, pointers

I have a simple application which requires the user to input details about students and their grades. I have two different classes `Student` and `Database`. The `Student` class contains info about students, such as, their names and grades:

`Student.h` file:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#include <string>

class Student {
private:
    std::string name;

public:
    Student(std::string name);

    const std::string getName() const;

    ~Student();
};

#endif // !STUDENT_H
```

`Student.cpp` file:

```
#include "student.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

Student::Student(std::string name) {
    this->name = name;
}

const std::string Student::getName() const {
    return this->name;
}

Student::~Student() {
    std::cout << "Student destructor\n";
}
```

`Database.h` file:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef DATABASE_H
#define DATABASE_H
#include <string>
#include "student.h"
#include <vector>

class StudentDatabase {
private:
    std::vector<Student*> student_list;

public:
    void add_student(Student* stud_obj);

    ~StudentDatabase();
};

#endif // !DATABASE_H
```

`Database.cpp` file:

```
#include "database.h"
#include "student.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void StudentDatabase::add_student(Student* stud_obj) {
    std::cout << "ADD STUDENT METHOD\n";
    StudentDatabase::student_list.push_back(stud_obj);
}

StudentDatabase::~StudentDatabase() {
    std::cout << "Database destructor\n";

    std::vector<Student*>::iterator iter;

    for (iter = student_list.begin(); iter != student_list.end(); iter++) {
        delete* iter;
    }
}
```

`Main.cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "database.h"
#include "student.h"

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::string name;

    StudentDatabase* database = new StudentDatabase();

    for (;;) {
        std::cout << "0: Add student \n";

        std::cout << "Enter a number (or q to quit) and press return... \n";

        std::cin >> input;
        std::cin.ignore();

        if (input == "q") {
            break;
        }

        else if (input == "0") {
            std::cout << "Enter student's first name: ";
            std::getline(std::cin, name);

            Student* student_obj = new Student(name, surname, student_number, grade);
            database->add_student(student_obj);
        }
    }

    delete database;
    return 0;
}
```

My question is: am I correctly deallocating memory for `Student`s from `~StudentDatabase()`?

I know smart pointers are more appropriate but I want to make sure I understand raw pointers properly.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! i have rolled back your last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: You should use smart pointers on your code in order to avoid issues with the memory.

Comment: Why are you even dynamically allocating objects in the first place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overall

You look like a Java programmer that is coming over to C++.

This:

```
{
    StudentDatabase* database = new StudentDatabase();
    ... STUFF
    delete database;
}
```

Is very bad practice.

1. There is no need to dynamically allocate this object (it can easily be an automatic variable thus creation and destruction is done automatically).
2. You don't guarantee that the `delete` is called.

You only need to dynamically allocate an object if the object lives past beyond the code that created it (here you don't). Even when this is needed you should be using smart pointers (probably `std::unique_ptr`) to correctly manage the lifespan of the dynamically created object.

Much easier to do:

```
{
    StudentDatabase database{};
    ... STUFF
}
```

---

You have not learned the rule of three. This is one of the most important concepts in C++. Until you have learned this rule you can not safely use pointers in the language.

### Code Review

This is fine for very small programs.

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
```

But you should make it a habit to make these longer and more unique. Personally I always use namespaces (that I know is unique to me) and add this to the include guard. A lot of IDE allow you to generate these guards with GUID.

---

When passing object to functions it is usually a good idea to pass them by reference to avoid a copy. To prevent accidental modification of the parameter you should pass by const reference.

```
    Student(std::string name);

    // Here I would change to:

    Student(std::string const& name);
```

---

The same applies to returning values (though there is more nuance to this, but as a beginner a good rule of thumb is return by const reference). Returning by reference (const if you don't want it to be changed). This will prevent the object being copied on returned. You then let the user of the function decide if they want a copy or to simply use the reference.

```
    const std::string getName() const;

    // Here I would change to:

    std::string const&  getName() const;
```

---

Prefer to use the initializer list in the constructor rather than code in the constructor.

```
Student::Student(std::string name) {
    this->name = name;
}
```

All member variables of a class are constructed before the code block of the constructor is executed. Thus in your case above you are constructing the object `name` then you are calling the `operator=` for the object `name` thus affectively initializing the variable twice. It works but this can potentially be inefficient if the constructor did a lot of work. Thus prefer to use the initializer list to prevent inefficiencies.

```
Student::Student(std::string const& name)
    : name(name)
{}
```

---

Also allow for the potential to use **move semantics**. This allows your object to take the content of the its parameters and avoid an extra copy.

```
Student::Student(std::string&& name) // Note the double &&
    : name(std::move(name))          // Move the name to this->name
{}
```

---

Prefer not to use `this->`.

This is actually an important one (in my opinion).  This actually causes more bugs than you think. The only reason to use `this->name` rather than `name` directly is because you have **shadowed** variables and you need to disambiguate the two usages.

The problem here is that when you make a mistake (and you will) the compiler can not detect the error.

So the better approach is to use better variable names so that you know from context the correct usage. Then you can turn on your compiler warnings and get the compiler to warn you when you do have shadowing so that you never have shadowed variables and thus do not need to disambiguate two similar named variables with `this->`.

---

I dislike this:

```
#include <string>
#include "student.h"
#include <vector>
```

Technically nothing wrong. But I order my includes in a specific order. Most specific to least specific.

```
#include "ThisClass.h"
#include "OtherClassesInThisLibrary.h"
---
#include "Other Local Libraries I Use .h"
#include <Other Gloval Libraries I Use .h>
---
#include <C++ header Files>
#include <C header Files>
```

Now the reason I do it this way is to make sure I don't hide errors around missing #include statements in my local files.

---

No reason to keep a vector of pointers.

```
    std::vector<Student*> student_list;
```

As you are not using polymorphism there is no need to store pointers. Simply store the object.

```
    std::vector<Student> student_list;
```

Ahh. I hear you say that it does not matter that much as I have fixed the destructor to correctly release the student objects. And yes you have. But you have forgotten to implement the rule of three. Which will make this code brittle and likely to cause errors.

Rule of 3: If your object contains an "owned" pointer then the compiler version of the constructors and assignment operators do not work correctly and thus you need to explicitly define these methods.

In your case you have a vector full of owned pointers (I know you own then because you try and delete them in the destructor).

How does this break your code I hear you ask:

```
{
    StudentDatabase    db1(

    db1.add_student(new Student("John"));

    StudentDatabase    db2(db1);
}
// Problem here.
// The "John" Student is deleted twice as both databases has a copy
// of the student.
```

But I will never copy the database (I hear you say). That's fine. Implement the rule of three by deleting the copy constructor and copy assignment operator and then nobody will ever have an accidental issue with your class.

Or:

Simply have a vector of Student (rather than vector of Student pointer). Alternatively If you want to share the object. Then we are back to using smart pointers.

---

This looks very weird.

```
    StudentDatabase::student_list.push_back(stud_obj);
```

This looks like you are accessing a class member (rather than a local object member). Looking back at your class definition it's a member of the local object.

```
    student_list.push_back(stud_obj);
```

---

Sure this is fine.

```
    for (iter = student_list.begin(); iter != student_list.end(); iter++) {
        delete* iter;
    }
```

But. If you look at other storage types (containers/arrays) they all destroy their objects in reverse order. So it may be holding to that standard and deleting them from the back rather than the front.

OR. You don't care about the order. Then we have a better for loop to achieve this:

```
    for (auto& obj: student_list) {
        delete obj;
    }
```

Comment: Good analysis. But: `StudentDatabase::student_list.push_back(stud_obj);` is legitimate: if you are in a derived class of `StudentDatabase` this is the syntax for getting the method of the base class. It's useful in case the derived class overrides the method. Not that that's the case here.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Yes it is valid. But that was not my point. It just looks weird. Looking weird is not a a good thing for maintenance. In this situation it is not required so best avoided to make the code look more standard.

Comment: Great in-depth answer. What exactly does the double `&&` in the `Student` constructor's parameter list do?

Comment: @mhmrhiman The double `&&` indicates to the compiler that the method can be called with an r-value reference. This is used to indicate parameters that can be moved. i.e. It is the way to implement move semantics for your class. If you don't "move" the object you will need to "copy" the object.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `new` everywhere. Inside your main function, the `StudentDatabase` could very well reside on the stack so you don't need to delete it yourself.

One of the issues with how `StudentDatabase` is written now is ownership semantics. Once a student pointer is added to the database, the database asumes ownership upon it and deletes it in the destructor. What if the same student pointer were to be added to multiple databases, or used after the database is deleted?

Smart pointers help prevent such errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should indeed use smart pointers. Consider what happens if you copy your database, which only copies the pointers to the students, then you delete the first database, which deletes the students and leaves you with dangling pointers. This is just bad design.

Also: `delete* iter` is typographically weird, even though the interpretation by the compiler is correct. The star belongs with the `iter`: you dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check this for yourself. Just define a variable `std::size_t activeStudents = 0` in `Student.cpp`, which you increase in the `Student` constructor and decrease in the destructor. If at the end of `main` this variable has the value 0, you're fine.

Same for the `StudentDatabase`.

This approach is only appropriate as long as you are learning about memory allocation and resource management. As soon as you think you undersand these topics, you should use an automatic tool like Valgrind to do the boring work for you.

By the way, your code doesn't compile. The `Student` constructor only accepts a single parameter, yet in `main` you pass 4 arguments:

```
new Student(name, surname, student_number, grade);
```

Next time you should better create a working example in your IDE, make sure that it compiles and then copy it directly to the Code Review question, without any furher edits.

Comment: I just tried it and it deallocates properly. I have also edited the part of the code which was preventing it from compiling. Thanks.

Comment: Beware of implicitly declared ctors though.

Comment: you should prefer something like libasan over a user implemented reference count